# Determining the zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Z}[Y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question states: does $\mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ have any zero divisors? My thought process was the following:

We call an element $a$ a zero divisor if $\exists b \neq 0 \in R$ such that $ab = 0$. We know that $0 = (0,0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Y}[Y]$. Let $a = (0, \sum^{n}_{i=1}a_{i}Y^{i})$ and $b = (\sum^{n}_{i=1}b_{i}X^{i}, 0)$, then $ab = (0 \cdot\sum^{n}_{i=1}b_{i}X^{i}, 0 \cdot\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_{i}Y^{i} ) = (0,0)$. So I think I found two nonzero element whose product is 0.

However, the answer model provided for this question, states that $\mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ does not have any zero divisors, since an element $(f,g) \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \times \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ is a zero divisor  is $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $g \in \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ are zero divisors. I understand that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[Y]$ do not have any zero divisors, but I do not understand the reasoning. $(0, f)$ or $(f,0)$ for an arbitrairy polynomial is considered a nonzero element, right?

Is there a mistake in my reasoning or is the answer model wrong?

Comment: You answer model is wrong (unless the question really was about $\Bbb Z[x]\otimes\Bbb Z[Y]$). A..direct product of two (or more) nonzero rings is never an integral domain, exactly because $(x,0).(0,y)=(0,0)$ always.

Comment: Life is more easy by finding more generally the set of zero divisors in a product of two integral domains. Then you won't be distracted by the specifics of polynomials.